# Hive and HBase Integration - Data access issue

Tags: c#, hadoop, hbase, hive, thrift

We have a problem in Hive accessing the data stored in HBase. The data is inserted by Thrift Client(C#) using TBinaryProtocol.

The same thing works if the data is inserted directly into HBase or using REST API.

If i use Impala to query the HBase table data, it is working fine for Binary data.

Is there a way to use TJsonProtocol in Thrift API (C# client) to inserted non-binary data.

Answer (score 0):

The Client must use the exact same protocol/transport stack as the Server does. If the Server offers an endpoint for the Thrift JSON protocol, then yes, this is possible, otherwise it is not.

However, I'm in doubt that this will really solve the problem, as it probably has nothing to do with the binary protocol or with JSON in general. To be able to provide a better answer, it could be very helpful to know the exact details of your problem.

If you are unsure how to improve your question, just follow the [common standard rules for outstanding problem descriptions](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html), in short:

1. what are you trying to do?
2. what did you expect to happen?
3. what happened instead?
4. what error messages do you get (if any)?
5. any other related fact that could possibly be helpful

The more Information we have, the better and the faster someone will bring up the right answer.